# Managing different methods for single action in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I am working on an application which is accessed using sub-domain. There are unique sub-domain for each client. In some cases I need different logic for different clients for eg file upload.

Can I configure in struts 2 such a way that with same action name I can call or redirect different methods in same action class ?

Comment: you can have "unspecified" method in your java class and pass parameters in the url and do conditional coding in the method and then return appropriate values

Comment: Thanks @therealprashant but it is really difficult to add parameters in the url. is there any other way like in interceptor I can add parameters to the url based on subdomain ?

Answer (score 1):

In struts 2 you can have different packages, methods but action URL can not be same.

Example:

```
    class UserAction extends ActionSupport
    {
     public String execute() throws Exception {
            return SUCCESS;
        }

     public string doDel() {
            return SUCCESS; 
            }
         public string doMod() {
            return SUCCESS;
        }
      }
```

In struts.xml

```
 <action name="*User" class="UserAction" method="{0}">
<result name="success">/User.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Now your actions will be as follows:

```
User - call execute method.
doModUser - call doModUser method.
doDelUser - call doDelUser method.
```

In your case you can do like this, send parameter to identify method and based on which call the relevant method.